# Power Visualization Map Sample Code in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to visualize data on a map with React js.

Does someone have a (full) React js sample code on visualizing data using a map in power view?

There are some examples on the internet but they're written in pure Javascript (not React js framework) and some of them don't provide the code (only as a ready-to-use dashboard).

Here are some samples of power view on a map:

https://carto.com//blog/demo/carto-now-available-for-deck-gl/

https://i.ytimg.com/vi/NRMEdscD6OE/maxresdefault.jpg

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7150848/45184557-73d16d00-b251-11e8-8e61-82cc53f00bb8.png

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the sample demo here https://deck.gl/examples/hexagon-layer/

[image: demo]

and the corresponding code here https://github.com/visgl/deck.gl/tree/8.4-release/examples/website/3d-heatmap

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "3d-heatmap",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start-local": "webpack-dev-server --env.local --progress --hot --open",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --progress --hot --open"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "d3-request": "^1.0.5",
    "deck.gl": "^8.4.0",
    "react": "^16.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.0",
    "react-map-gl": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1"
  }
}
```

index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>deck.gl Example</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {margin: 0; font-family: sans-serif; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; overflow: hidden;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  App.renderToDOM(document.getElementById('app'));
</script>
</html>
```

app.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {StaticMap} from 'react-map-gl';
import {AmbientLight, PointLight, LightingEffect} from '@deck.gl/core';
import {HexagonLayer} from '@deck.gl/aggregation-layers';
import DeckGL from '@deck.gl/react';

// Source data CSV
const DATA_URL =
  'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/visgl/deck.gl-data/master/examples/3d-heatmap/heatmap-data.csv'; // eslint-disable-line

const ambientLight = new AmbientLight({
  color: [255, 255, 255],
  intensity: 1.0
});

const pointLight1 = new PointLight({
  color: [255, 255, 255],
  intensity: 0.8,
  position: [-0.144528, 49.739968, 80000]
});

const pointLight2 = new PointLight({
  color: [255, 255, 255],
  intensity: 0.8,
  position: [-3.807751, 54.104682, 8000]
});

const lightingEffect = new LightingEffect({ambientLight, pointLight1, pointLight2});

const material = {
  ambient: 0.64,
  diffuse: 0.6,
  shininess: 32,
  specularColor: [51, 51, 51]
};

const INITIAL_VIEW_STATE = {
  longitude: -1.415727,
  latitude: 52.232395,
  zoom: 6.6,
  minZoom: 5,
  maxZoom: 15,
  pitch: 40.5,
  bearing: -27
};

const MAP_STYLE = 'https://basemaps.cartocdn.com/gl/dark-matter-nolabels-gl-style/style.json';

export const colorRange = [
  [1, 152, 189],
  [73, 227, 206],
  [216, 254, 181],
  [254, 237, 177],
  [254, 173, 84],
  [209, 55, 78]
];

function getTooltip({object}) {
  if (!object) {
    return null;
  }
  const lat = object.position[1];
  const lng = object.position[0];
  const count = object.points.length;

  return `\
    latitude: ${Number.isFinite(lat) ? lat.toFixed(6) : ''}
    longitude: ${Number.isFinite(lng) ? lng.toFixed(6) : ''}
    ${count} Accidents`;
}

/* eslint-disable react/no-deprecated */
export default function App({
  data,
  mapStyle = MAP_STYLE,
  radius = 1000,
  upperPercentile = 100,
  coverage = 1
}) {
  const layers = [
    new HexagonLayer({
      id: 'heatmap',
      colorRange,
      coverage,
      data,
      elevationRange: [0, 3000],
      elevationScale: data && data.length ? 50 : 0,
      extruded: true,
      getPosition: d => d,
      pickable: true,
      radius,
      upperPercentile,
      material,

      transitions: {
        elevationScale: 3000
      }
    })
  ];

  return (
    <DeckGL
      layers={layers}
      effects={[lightingEffect]}
      initialViewState={INITIAL_VIEW_STATE}
      controller={true}
      getTooltip={getTooltip}
    >
      <StaticMap reuseMaps mapStyle={mapStyle} preventStyleDiffing={true} />
    </DeckGL>
  );
}

export function renderToDOM(container) {
  render(<App />, container);

  require('d3-request').csv(DATA_URL, (error, response) => {
    if (!error) {
      const data = response.map(d => [Number(d.lng), Number(d.lat)]);
      render(<App data={data} />, container);
    }
  });
}
```